# CheckStyle Intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Ребят, подскажите, как в Intellij соответственно настроить чек стайл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

этот случай касается только конкретно лямбд с блоками внутри

Comment: Не понял, что вы хотите?

Comment: нужно настроить отступы конкретно только для блоков в лямбдах